# Can't use break statement. Illegal expression error

Tags: pascal, freepascal, lazarus

In my for loop I used break statement to break loop after some match. But when I compile my code I got error for break:

```
Error: Illegal expression
```

Could you help me? I should add some unit?

```
for i:=0 to length(carsList)-1 do
        begin

             if numer <> carsList[i].numer then
             begin
                  tmpKw2 := carsList[i].rectangleRotate(carsList[i].angle);

                  if((polyLine(tmpKw2,linia.p1.x,linia.p1.y,linia.p2.x,linia.p2.y))) then
                  begin
                       kolizja := true;
                       break:=true;
                       maxV := carsList[i].v;
                       Break;
                  end;
             end;
        end;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code below works for me:

```
program Testbreak;

procedure TestBreakInFor;
var
    i : Integer;
begin
  for i := 0 to 10 do begin
    if Odd(i) then
      Break;
  end;
end;

begin
  TestBreakInFor;
  readln;
end.
```

The reason you are getting the "Illegal expression" error is that you are attempting to use `Break` as if it were a variable (`Break := True`) when it is not, it is an execution flow-control instruction, like `Continue`.  Omit the  `:= True` and it should compile corrrectly.

Comment: omg now I see.... I used variable with name Break..... thank you for open my eyes! :)